# How to retrieve url from firebase database and show url via UIButton (SWIFT)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I m trying to get Url of pdf from the firebase database and show that URL as a PDF via UIButton (iOS).
I'm trying different ways but I can not get it to work.
any help will be much appreciated

```
      import UIKit
```

import SafariServices
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase
import WebKit

class ModelsInfoController: UIViewController , UIWebViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate, WKUIDelegate {
var WKwebView: WKWebView!
var dbRef: DatabaseReference!
var nextUrl = "https://www.google.co.uk/"

```
let infoBttn: UIButton = {
    
    let infoBttn = UIButton (type: .system)
    infoBttn.setTitle("More Info", for: .normal)
    infoBttn.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    infoBttn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    infoBttn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(retrieveUrl), for: .touchUpInside)
    return infoBttn
```

}()

```
  @objc  func retrieveUrl () {
       dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("models")
       dbRef.observe(.value) {
           (snapshot) in
           let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
           let url = value["url"]!
           self.nextUrl = (url as! String)
        print (self.nextUrl)
           print ("webview is about to load")
        let request = URLRequest (url: URL(string: self.nextUrl)!)
           self.WKwebView.load(request)
           self.WKwebView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: .new, context: nil)
       }
       print ("function observe is called")
   }
```

I got this error :

> Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x102d85dd0) to 'NSDictionary' (0x102d856c8)

It is not fetching the correct URL from database (where there are different URL, for different models).

I fixed that error, but still is not opening the pdf when I press the button.

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: @CongNguyen i did, thanks

Comment: What does this mean `show that URL as a PDF via UIButton`?

Comment: @CongNguyen i want to fetch the url from the DB, and when the button is pressed shows pdf for that specific child

Comment: You want to display the PDF content by using WKWebView, right?

Comment: @CongNguyen yes

Comment: And you don't get what you want in the web view?

Comment: @CongNguyen nope, i get this error : Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x102d85dd0) to 'NSDictionary' (0x102d856c8). and is not fetching the correct URL from database (where there are different URL, for different models)

Comment: The error is quite clear, please fix it first.

Comment: @CongNguyen thanks, that error is fixed. but still is not opening the pdf when I press the button. any idea?

Comment: What are you doing in your button action? Are you presenting a new screen with webview?

Comment: @Jithin yes correct. i did call here bttn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(retrieveUrl), for: .touchUpInside) (i think is not correct, for this i asking for help)

Comment: Can you put your full source code? or a sample project if you can

Comment: @CongNguyen i did add the codes that are related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code but the main one is understanding the data you're retrieving with .value

What you have now is this

```
func retrieveUrl () {
   dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("models")
   dbRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
      let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
```

and the problem is that 'models' contains other child info. Your structure may be like this:

```
models
   model_0
      url: "some url"
   model_1
      url: "another url"
```

As you can see, if 'models' is observed by .value, all of that data within 'models' is loaded and there is no direct child 'url' - the direct children are model_0, model_1 etc

So, if you know the specific model url you want, change the ref

```
let ref = your_firebase.child("models").child("model_1").child("url")
ref.observeSingleEvent.. { snapshot in
   let url = snapshot.value as? String ?? "No Url"
   print(url) //prints 'another url'
```

Note that I am also using .observeSingleEvent instead of .observe. That's because .observe leaves an observer on that node and will continue to fire events if any data changes and it doesn't appear you want that for this use case.

To other things to note:

This line

```
print ("function observe is called")
```

will execute before the data is loaded from Firebase. Code is faster than the internet so firebase data is only valid wihin the closure following the function - any code *after* the closure will execute first.

You may also be having a rules issue. For testing, ensure they are set to true to eliminate them as an issue. Be sure to reset them after testing to protect your data.

Comment: thank you. any idea why the action is not happening to show the link?

Comment: @levikoci That's a separate issue. You need to get the Firebase part working first. Ensure the data is loaded and var populated by adding a print(url) statement as shown in my answer. Once that's working the other issues can be addressed.